# Power Query / Power BI get look for data from another excel workbook

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerbi, increment, powerquery

I am trying to combine worksheets from two different workbooks with Power Query and I have trouble doing that.

I do not want to merge the two workbooks.

I do not want to create relationships or "joints".

However, I want to get very specific information for one workbook which has only one column. The "ID" column.

The ID column has rows with letter tags : AB or BE.
Following these letters, sepcific numeric ranges are associated.
For both AB and BE, number ranges first from 0000 to 3000 and from 3000 to 6000.

I thus have the following possibilities:
From AB0000 to AB3000
From AB3001 to AB6000
From BE0000 to BE3000
From BE3001 to AB6000

Each category match to the a specific item in my column geography, from the other workbook:
From AB0000 to AB3000, it is ItalyZ
From AB3001 to AB6000, it is ItalyB
From BE0000 to BE3000, it is UKY
From BE3001 to AB6000, it is UKM

I am thus trying to find the highest number associated to the first AB category, the second AB category, the first BE category, and the second.

I then want to "bring" this number in the other query and increment it each time that matching country is found in the other workbook.
For example :

AB356 is the highest number in the first workbook.

Once the first "ItalyB" is found, the column besides writes "AB357".
Once the second is "ItalyB" is found, the column besides write "AB358".

Here is the one columned worksheet:
[image: ![input]

Here is the other worksheet with the various countries in geography:
[image: input]

Here is an example of results: 
[image: result]

have one column (geography) with 
I think that this is something which I should work towards:

I added the index column, with a start as one, because each row (even row zero) should increment either of the four matching code.
[image]

In order to keep moving forward I have also been trying to create some sort of mapping in third excel sheet, that I imported in Power BI, but I am not sure that this is a good way forward:

[image: mapping]

I have the following result when I create a blank query:
[image]

After a correction, I still get this result when creating the blank query:
[image]

Comment: Good job, I gave you 10 points on the question because I know how much work you did. We have a bit of a problem here because we need to have a kind of order on the rows for our DAX. If you have 4 times ItalyZ, how do you know which one is firts? Without this we cannot get the result you want. Is there a date column or an ID? If not we will need to make in index in m-guery.

Comment: Thank you ! I hope to have enough mastery at some point to gie points and answer questions. I am loosing my mind with Power BI and my workbook. To answer the question: the order is not strongly important. I could have 4 times ItalyZ, or even 100 occurrences of ItalyZ. Whichever "appears" first in my "geogrpaphy" column should be incremented, going top down (first row), but the DAX or Power Query could as well "start" at very end of my Geography column and start increment from that point. So in, in order to "create" a "fake" order I should create a Index column after "geography" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an easy answer as there are many steps to get to your result. I have choosen for m-query because of the complexity.

In PBi click on Transform data, now you are in m-query.

1. The table with the ID's (I called it "HighestID") needs expansion
   because we need to be able to map on prefix
2. You need a mapping table
   ("GeoMapping"), else there is no relation between the Prefixes and
   the geolocation.
3. We need the newID on the Geo-table (which I called "Geo").

**Expand the HighestID table.**

Click on the table and open the Advanced Editor, look at your code and compare it to the one below, the last 2 steps are essential, there I add two columns (Prefix and Number) which we need later.

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("...\HighestID.csv"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=1, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"ID", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Prefix", each Text.Middle([ID],0,2), type text),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Number", each Number.FromText(Text.Middle([ID],2,5)))
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

Result:
[image]

**Create mapping table**

Click right button under your last table and click Blank Query:
[image]

Paste the source below, ensure the name of the merg table equals the name of your table. As I mentioned, I called it HighestID.

```
let
    Source = #table({"Prefix", "Seq_Start", "Seq_End","GeoLocation"},{{"AB",0,2999,"ItalyZ"},{"AB",3000,6000,"ItalyB"},{"BC",0,299,"UKY"},{"BC",3000,6000,"UKM"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Seq_Start", Int64.Type}, {"Seq_End", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Prefix"}, HighestID, {"Prefix"}, "HighestID", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded HighestID" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "HighestID", {"Number"}, {"Number"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded HighestID", each [Number] >= [Seq_Start] and [Number] <= [Seq_End]),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Prefix", "Seq_Start", "Seq_End", "GeoLocation"}, {{"NextSeq", each List.Max([Number]) + 1, type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Result:
[image]

**Adding the NextSeq Column**

This is the hard bit because when I would only give you teh code, I am afraid it will not work so I give you the steps you need to do.

1.Select the table, right click on Geography and click Group by. select as below:
[image]

2. Merge with table Geomapping as below:
   [image]
3. Expand the GeoMapping with NextSeq
   [image]
4. Add a custom column:
   [image]
5. Remove columns not needed so only custom is left created in step 4.
6. Expand the column (all select). End result all your columns you had earlier plus an Index column.

[image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough ! However, I am stuck when I am creating the new blanck query, despite having rename the sheet "Higest ID". I have added the result that I get in my question.

Comment: It is not Higest ID, but HighestID

Comment: What is the error you are getting? When you look to the left you see the steps m-query is taking. Start with first step and see if this gives error, go to the step giving the error..

Comment: You have a lot of #(cr) and #(lf) in your code, this means you copy/paste them (are you using a MAC?), you need to get rid of them by editing.

Comment: Thank you !!! It is done ! I had an error with the last costum column. The error was "Index" already used, so I used "Index2" in the formula. I do not why but now this is ok. Thank you !!

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help!

Comment: This is absolutly awesome. I wish to understand this better and I cannot thank enough !

Comment: I am going to test and test again with various iterations in the coming hours and days, but my big question is: will this work If I keep having new ID comming in, and new "geographies" observation, will I be able to simply refresh the data as long my two files remain with the same name ?

Comment: Hello Tomas, yes it will, on the refresh it will recalculate the ids so you will be all good. The only worry I have is that you can have only a max of 3000 as that is your span on each serie.

Comment: Now I am trying to apply through a merge of two files, thus continuing the series...I thought that because the column "has a beginning" it would much simpler but this case is also a headache...